# Identify this Movie about a world full of Vampires searching for supplement for blood

Tags: identify-this-movie

Identify this Hollywood movie set in a world where maximum of world population become vampire and they live in fear of sunlight in closed houses with black or closed windows and having black window cars with camera fitted to give outside view.

Story is about two brother(One of them is a human blood hunter and other is Scientist researching for cure for need of blood). Even coffee shops use a little bit of blood in coffee to sell it and day by day percentage of blood in coffee reduced due to shortage of blood.

The scientist person come in contact with the human girl and its group and an Ex-vampire(who became human due to exposure of sun). They together find the cure to transform vampire back to human. But the head of vampires doesn't accept it and in final battle the scientist looses his brother in fight.

There is also some different kind of Vampires lives in basements which was killed under sunlight by authorities due to lack of blood.

I didn't remember the release year/cast etc but its look new to me, may be 20's movie but not sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is most probably [*Daybreakers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433362/). I cannot say much to prove my claim, other than that its plot matches your descriptions in pretty much every aspect, as can be seen from the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daybreakers).